# Not getting ellipses at the end of attributed text when created from html text

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

In JSON I am getting some text in form of html. I am showing this text on UILable using NSAtrributed text. I have set maximum number of lines for UIlable = 3, Html text is displayed fine but I want ellipses(3 dots ...) at the end of 3rd line if text to be displayed is above 3 lines. ellipses is not coming, I have also tried paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail.

I am using below mentioned function for creating attributed text from html text.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
convenience init(html:String , font : UIFont) throws {
    guard let data = html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "Invalid HTML", code: -500, userInfo: nil)
    }
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 19
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 21
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 0
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0

    let options = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSNumber(unsignedInteger:NSUTF8StringEncoding),NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0),NSFontAttributeName : font ]
    try self.init(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
}}
```

I am calling above extension in below mentioned way

```
        var description = "<p>Some Html Text above 3 lines</p>"
        self.lblDescription.numberOfLines = 3
        self.lblDescription.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        lblDescription.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping
        let trimmed = description.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
        let htmlText =  "<body style='font-family:Gotham-Book ;font-size: 16px';><style>p {margin-bottom: -20px;}</style>\(trimmed)</body>"
        let attributedText = try? NSMutableAttributedString(html :htmlText, font: self.lblDescription.font)
        self.lblDescription.attributedText = attributedText
```

I am not getting where I am getting wrong, I have tried with number of solutions from stack overflow. Please some one provide me solution for this.

Comment: `lblDescription.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping` shouldn't that avoid the 3 dots? What if you do `lblDescription.lineBreakMode = . ByTruncatingTail` instead?

Comment: After your reply I have tried combinations  1. Extension and Label without  lineBreakMode 2. Extension and Label with  lineBreakMode= .ByTruncatingTail  3. Extension and Label with  lineBreakMode= .ByClippingWord   ...But still same result not getting ellipses...Are you getting at your end...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? @Sandy